# get email id's into an array from multiple checkboxes to send email

Tags: arrays, sendmail

I'm trying to send mail to multiple users from sendgrid API.

I have to provide select box option to the end users to select their required emails from the available list.

HTML page looks Like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<? echo $email1 ?>"/> email id1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<? echo $email2 ?>"/> Email id2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<? echo $email3 ?>"/> email id3<br/>
```

PHP code part is :

```
$checked = $_POST['options'];
for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){


$options[] = $_POST['options[]'] ? $_POST['options[]']  : '';
    $toList = array($_POST['email_to'],$checked[$i]); }
```

When i select and sent mail to more than 2 check boxes only 2 mail id's are receiving the mail.

That means one is a default email id in the "$toList" and the second one is from the "$checked[$i]".

If i uncheck all the check boxes to send only to the default email id getting this error: "Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to SendGrid\Mail::setTos() must be an array, null given,".

What is the error in my code. or is there any better way to achieve my requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$options[] = isset($_POST['options[]']) && $_POST['options[]']  ? "1" : "0";
```

is incorrect. The `[]` will be stripped off the form names and turned into an array. You use `$_POST['options'][$i]` to access the individual elements.

Comment: Hi Thanks for ur reply, with out this line of code also i'm unable to send mail more than 2 users. I tried just now.